# Aplicar función para procesar un campo en laravel previo a ser llamado con eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo en la base de datos el nombre de una imagen, la cual quiero convertir a una ruta completa mediante una función que reciba el nombre de la imagen y le asigne la ruta previa en el servidor.

Mis consultas las estoy haciendo con eager loading en cascada **tabla1.tabla2.tabla3** por lo cual me retorna el nombre de la imagen, no una url, ya que para obtener la url debo aplicar una función.

He revisado la documentación pero no he encontrado algo que pueda ayudarme.

¿Como puedo modificar el modelo para que siempre me retorne un campo procesado con una función creada por mi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la respuesta de Leonardo no te sirve, que era lo mismo que pensé en un comienzo, quizás lo que buscas es algo más versátil.  Te recomiendo [Fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal)

Con Fractal puedes devolver tus datos transformados (serializados) de la manera que necesites, como una colección de algún modelo, pero entregada de diferentes maneras en diferentes circunstancias.

Por ejemplo, quizás quieres que Al ser llamado desde el Api, un cierto modelo devuelva todos o algunos de sus atributos pero modificados a partir de ciertos métodos.  Lo que se hace, es tener "Transformadores" para cada situación.

Por ejemplo, podrías devolver tus Productos con el transformador ProductosParaIndexDelApi.  Que los devolverá transformando sus atributos o incluso agregando atributos nuevos, a partir de los criterios que necesites.

Si esto se ajusta a lo que quieres, puedes comentar y puedo editar la respuesta con algún ejemplo en caso de que la documentación no te lo deje muy claro.

**EDICIÓN**
Un ejemplo:
Archivo para serializar tu Modelo de una manera específica:

**Transformador Fractal**

```
namespace App\Modules\ERP\Models\PuntoVenta\Fractal;

use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
use App\Modules\ERP\Models\PuntoVenta\PuntoVenta;

class PuntoVentaDistribucionFolioTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(PuntoVenta $puntoVenta)
    {
        return [
            'id'     => (int) $puntoVenta->id,
            'nombre' => $puntoVenta->nombreCompuesto,
            'servidor_id' => (int) $puntoVenta->servidor_id,
            'foliosPorTipo' => $puntoVenta->cantidadFoliosPorTipoDte()
        ];
    }
}
```

En este transformador, me traigo solamente algunos atributos de mi modelo, además, agrego un atributo "foliosPorTipo" que no existe en el modelo y que se completa según un método que creé.

Para lograr traer esto, en tu **Controlador**, tendrías que hacer algo similar a:

```
<?php
namespace App\Modules\ERP\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Modules\ERP\Models\PuntoVenta\PuntoVenta;
use App\Modules\ERP\Models\PuntoVenta\Fractal\PuntoVentaTransformer;
use App\Modules\ERP\Models\PuntoVenta\Fractal\PuntoVentaDistribucionFolioTransformer;
use Fractal;

class PuntoVentaController extends Controller
{
    public function paraDistribucion()
    {
        $puntosVenta = PuntoVenta::orderBy('servidor_id')
                                 ->orderBy('nombre')
                                 ->get();

        $resource = Fractal::collection($puntosVenta)
                           ->transformWith(
                               new PuntoVentaDistribucionFolioTransformer()
                           );
        return $resource;
    }
}
```

En resumen, en mi controlador estoy pidiendo que se transforme una colección, para traerla de la manera que la necesito utilizando un transformador para mi Modelo.
También podría transformar una instancia, utilizando el método item de Fractal en lugar de collection...

Esta es **una** de varias maneras que aparecen en la documentación de Fractal, es la que me acomoda, siempre en mis modelos agrego un namespace /Fractal y ahí agrego un transformador base (donde a veces oculto el id por un id público o no lo traigo en lo absoluto) y algunos otros transformadores si es necesario...

Espero te sirva de algo el ejemplo.

Comment: Era lo que buscaba, un ejemplo seria de ayuda :)

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo, espero que sea finalmente la respuesta correcta y no me haya ido por las ramas.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), para "pre-tratar" la salida de una propiedad de tu modelo.

Por ejemplo:

1- En tu modelo (supongamos que se llama Producto) defines el Accessor, suponiendo que el campo en tu tabla se llama imagen:

```
class Producto extends Model

    /* todo tu codigo */

    public function getImagenAttribute($value)
    {
        return asset(this->value);
    }
}
```

Y es es todo, luego cuando desde blade lo llames de devolvera la url completa a la imagen.

```
{{ $producto->imagen }}
```

Comment: Es para una api, lo que busco es poder ejecutar una función que pueda modificar las propiedades del modelo antes de ser llamado mediante eager loading para que cuando realice una consulta ya poder tener la ruta de la imagen completa.

Comment: Agrega el código que estas usando a tu pregunta, realmente no me queda claro.